# How to dynamically set the node name in xslt

Tags: xslt

I would like to dynamically set the node name in XSLT.

My XSLT looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="sam" select="elementName"/>
       <Body>
      <xsl:element name="{$sam}">
             <PacketControlInfo>
                  <abc>123</abc>
             </PacketControlInfo>
         </xsl:element>
       </Body>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

After `Body`, I want the node name to be set by the variable `"sam"`, `<xsl:element name="{$sam}">`. Can someone please help, so that my output should like this?

```
<Body>
  <elementName>
         <PacketControlInfo>
              <abc>123</abc>
         </PacketControlInfo>
     </elementName>
   </Body>
```

It can be seen in the above XML that the node name below `Body` has been changed to `"elementName"`, the value of the variable `"sam"`.

Comment: Where is the "dynamic" part? You want your variable to be a constant; why do you need it at all?

Answer (score 4):

The `select` attribute is an XPath expression. When you declare the variable as

```
<xsl:variable name="sam" select="elementName"/>
```

then doing `<xsl:element name="{$sam}"/>` will try and take the element name from the *value* of an element named `elementName` at the root of your input XML document, and if there is no such element it'll try and create an element whose name is the empty string, which is not allowed.

If you want to set the variable to the actual string "elementName" you need extra quotes:

```
<xsl:variable name="sam" select="'elementName'"/>
```

Comment: But of course if you want to have an element whose name is a known string, you can simply write it to the output as  `<elementName>` and avoid all this song and dance...

Comment: @HarikrishnaKalarickel, this would be same as `<xsl:variable name="sam">elementName</xsl:variable>`.